# Prove that there exists a linear functional f in the dual space of V*

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let W be a subspace of codimension 1 of an n-dimensional vector space V.  Prove that there exists a linear functional f in V* whose kernel is W.

I'm not sure whether my proof is correct.  It goes like this

Let $C = \{b_1,b_2,...,b_{n-1}\}$ be a basis of W.  Then we can extend it to be a basis of of V say $B = \{b_1,...,b_n\}$.  Define f:V -> $F$ by $f(b_i)=0$ if i = 1,2,..., n-1 and $f(b_n)=1$.  Then f is in V* and clearly ker(f) is W.

Is this alright

Thank you.